# Hudson build timeout plugin

Tags: hudson-plugins

Do you guys know how to check out hudson build timeout plugin's source code ?
I could find only the jenkins build timeout plugin's source code.

https://github.com/hudson-plugins doesn't contain build-timeout plugin